# Convert TempData to Int

Tags: c#, tempdata

I have a problem to convert TempData["Id"] to int. I assign an int value to the TempData["Id"], and want to use it as int. Here is my code:

```
 TempData["Id"] = 1;
 int Id= (int)TempData["Id"];
```

But it didn't work. The Id is null. I try to use some suggestion like

```
Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Id"];
Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Id"].ToString());
```

But it also shows null. Please help

Comment: We have no idea what type `TempData` is - you've given us no context. Please provide a [mcve] or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: please provide code that is easy to copy-paste. it should be able to run after a single copy paste.

Comment: @MongZhu: From the example it is impossible to tell what type the id is. It could be `object`, which is more likely because of the following typecast.

Comment: I want to pass the int value 1 through tempdata. So i write like this  TempData["Id"] = 1;

Comment: @yusry post your entire code. If we don't know what type TempData is we cant help you

Comment: @yusry but still you don't show how you instantiate TempData what type is it? Is it a Dictionary<string, int> ?

Comment: @MongZhu im pretty sure he was talking about TempData["Id"] being null